# Cannot upload most video files to supabase server in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, encoding, expo, supabase

I have the issue that some files, for example many videos seemingly cannot be properly uploaded with base64 encoding, but with React Native the update function of supabase only works with base64 encoding, i can't upload them. Is there any workaround i haven't seen yet? Any help is appreciated!

This is my code:

```
      const base64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(uri, {
        encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
      });

      const { error } = await supabase.storage
        .from("files")
        .upload(filePath, decode(base64), {
          contentType: mimeType,
        });
```

The error i get: "TypeError: Network request failed"

Documentation of supabase: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/storage-from-upload?example=upload-file-using-arraybuffer-from-base64-file-data

[Supabase documentation. Upload only possible with base64 encoding?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vicEF.png)

I tried using a different encoding function, upload with blob and just directly giving the function the file returned by the DocumentPicker. Looked up if any other variables are incorrect, but everything else works as it should. Images and even one specific video are being uploaded correctly.
The DocumentPicker (from expo):

```
      result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        type: "*/*", // Allow all file types
        copyToCacheDirectory: true,
      });
```

I really don't know how i could fix this. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Despite the specification says `FormData` does not work as intended, this works. Here `uri` is from `ImagePicker`.

```
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append("file", {
  name: "0B5E8DE9-0388-48D7-996C-1E2FAC9A812C.jpg",
  type: "image/jpg",
  uri: "file:///Users/.../ImagePicker/0B5E8DE9-0388-48D7-996C-1E2FAC9A812C.jpg",
});

const { error } = await supabase.storage
  .from("files")
  .upload(filePath, formData);
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The append function seems to work in React Native a little bit different than in React. But an approach with formData in React Native doesnt work either. One thing which i seem to get now (i don't know why i didn't get that before) is that i get with my original code the warning: "Error: Cannot create URL for blob" even with the images (They are still uploaded correctly).  I suppose that i am creating a blob through the definition of the constant "base64", but shouldn't "decode(base64)" take care of that? I shouldn't be uploading a blob.

Comment: The issue was that the base nginx upload maximum is at 1MB, so every file above 1 MB wasn't uploadable. The file with under 300 kb was a mistake on my behalf, i probably misread.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see in the Supabase documentation that they [recommend that you use TUS Resumable Uploads](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/storage/uploads/standard-uploads#:%7E:text=Though%20you%20can%20upload%20up,in%20size%20for%20better%20reliability.) for any file larger than 5MB? (Remember: base64 encoding will greatly increase the size of your data.)

Comment: I didn't see that. Thanks! A video file with less than 300 KB however shouldn't be inflated to more than 5MB, right? I will keep that information in mind, but first i want to actually be able to upload videos in general.